# Javascript ' Array ' and ' Loop ' how can " variable[i] " be a CONDITION

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Here in this script cars[i] is used as a condition how is does the program identify weather the condition is `true` or `false` and the program stops correctly after it enters the 4th variable in the array ?

So the question is : how the program identifies the condition and how is cars[i] a condition.

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var i = 0;
var text = "";

for (;cars[i];) {
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to understand the code or asking for help to do something ?

Comment: I am asking you to help understand the code,its confusing I cant move forward

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things are at work here:

1. In JavaScript, when you use a value as a condition, it's coerced to be a boolean. The values `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, and `undefined` coerce to `false` (they, plus `false`, are called "falsey" values); all others ("truthy values") coerce to `true`.
2. If you try to access a non-existant entry in an array, you get back `undefined`.

So when `i` reaches `4`, `cars[i]` is `undefined`, which coerces to `false`, and the loop stops. But relying on that is likely to be setting a trap, because if there are any entries in `cars` that coerce to `false` (there aren't in that example, but...), the loop will stop before processing the entire array.

---

Side note: `for (; condition ;)` is a very strange way to write `while (condition)`. If you don't have initialize, test, and update parts, `for` probably isn't the control structure you want. You've said you're trying to understand this code, so I'm guessing you didn't write it; just beware that the quality may not be that high.

Here's the "normal" way to write that loop:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var i;
var text = "";
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}
```

Or something a bit more modern:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var text = "";
cars.forEach(function(car) {
    text += car + "<br>";
});
```

Or something a bit more advanced, but perhaps offputting for beginners:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var text = cars.reduce(function(acc, car) {
    return acc + car + "<br>";
}, "");
```

Comment: Pointing out that `for (; condition ;)` is essentially just a `while (condition)` is probably the most important part. Since `i` is being both initialized and updated, the code should have been `for (var i = 0; condition; i++)`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  If i="0 then it is a false statement right ?

Comment: @JokerSpirit: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder See you said "",0,NAN are false values right ?here the variable i=0;then the condition is false right. then the loop should stop.

Comment: @JokerSpirit: *Falsey*, not false. Yes, if you did `i = 0` and then you used `i` as the condition, it would be false and the loop would stop. Note that that's not what I'm doing anywhere in the answer, though. The only loop using `i` in the answer is `for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)`. The condition in that is `i < cars.length`, not `i`.